# StatusBar backgroundColor removed after pressing back button (android)

Tags: react-native

I'm using the StatusBar component in react native (Android). Here is an example code from my App.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { RootNavigator } from './components/Router';

export default class MainApp extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='black' barStyle="light-content"/>
        <RootNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The StatusBar is working properly when you launch the app, when you navigate through the entire app and when put in background and then return.

It's NOT working when exiting the app by pressing back button. When you launch the app again, the statusbar backgroundColor is suddenly grey (default color).

Is this a known bug or something? I can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, shortly after submitting the question I found out about another strategy, using imperative API. I avoided it at first since according to official documentation:

> For cases where using a component is not ideal, there
>   is also an imperative API exposed as static functions on the
>   component. It is however not recommended to use the static API and the
>   component for the same prop because any value set by the static API
>   will get overriden by the one set by the component in the next render.

Here is my revised code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { RootNavigator } from './components/Router';

export default class MainApp extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('black');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='black' barStyle="light-content"/>
        <RootNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It seems like this works properly now. When I press the back button and launch the app again the statusbar remains black. I won't declare this as the correct answer just yet in case someone has an explanation why this happens or a better solution.

**Edit**: This also appears to work only 90% of the time or so. I've noticed, once in a while, when pressing back button and returning the statusbar remained grey. It is absolutely boggling at this point, I suppose componentWillMount isn't always triggered?

**Edit2**: After switching to componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount as suggested, it seems to be working 100% of the time now.

Comment: You might want to use constructor or `componentDidMount` instead, since `componentWillMount` is marked as unsafe and will be deprecated soon https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: Interesting, I will adjust my code and see if it's better. Thanks.

Comment: Well, using componentDidMount does seem to work 100% of the time. A bit surprising, but good to know. I guess I won't be using componentWillMount anymore.